# Why do I need to use nuget to add ASP.NET Core packages into my project if I already have the SDK installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This doesn't make sense to me. If they're already on my system, shouldn't a using declaration be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't use the asp.net core project template ("File", "New Project", "Web", "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)".
I did and choosed "Empty Project" after that, and i had a reference to .NETCoreApp (1.0.1 in my case)